# Fastest leaf tree search

Tags: c++, tree

Say i have a tree implementation like this (simplified):

```
class Node 
{
public:
    std::string name;
    int attr_1;
    double attr_2;
    unsigned int nChildren;
    Node* Children;
}
```

If i need to get a specific Node by its attribute or name, do i need to loop through every single child node from the root to find it? Or is there a faster search algorithm, or faster/better tree implementation? Say, i need to find a node by its class and id attributes, like when i need to apply a CSS rule or something.

Comment: You can have another hashmap, mapping the attribute with a specific value to a set of nodes. Lookup will be faster, it depends on how many leafs in your tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current draft I assume that the only possible way to find a `Node` with a specific `name`, `id`, `class` any other data is to traverse the tree looking at **every** node. The time complexity would be **O(nNodes)**.

You might be interested in binary search trees which allows you to do search operations in **O(log(nNodes))** which is way more faster! However they require some additional effort to stay valid when you add/remove node. Also it is important to keep the tree balanced which is the main requirement for **O(log(nNodes))** time.

**Edit 1**

I am familiar with css syntax. It is quit complicated to implement at tree to fulfil all css requirements. Here indeed binary search tree cannot represent a DOM tree. A DOM tree should be represented by Node, references to its children and possible to its parent. A binary search tree may store a references to these Nodes and successfully serve the search queries by `id` for example. But if any node is removed/added/id changes the binary search tree should react accordingly.

Comment: And what will be the sorting key of the binary tree??

Comment: But that wouldnt work for a DOM Tree, would it? as these can have multiple children

Comment: Just for the lookup - would it be a good idea to scan the tree beforehand (on load time), and put pointers to the nodes in appropriate hashmaps? so i can do a fast lookup, and dont have to traverse the tree every time?

Comment: @calcyss. It might be a good decision. If you often search by `id` with a hashmap you instantly get what your are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no rules defining where a node can / can't be, you have to scan all nodes till you find the match.

There's no magical guessing in algorithms.